# How to edit StringCollection in C# PropertyGrid? ["Constructor in type 'System.string' not found"]

Tags: c#, propertygrid, stringcollection

Using Settings Editor I created some user settings for my application. In one specific instance, I need a setting to be an array of strings. The only option I encounter is StringCollection:

[Choosing the data type in settings editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoE0E.png)

When I edit the content while still in Settings Editor (clicking on the three dots) a simple editor gets invoked, where I can enter my strings, line by line:

[String Collection Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45xNv.png)

I created a simple form for my users to edit those settings, creating a PropertyGrid and tying it to the default settings:

```cs
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

When I edit the StringCollection there, I get a different String Collection Editor:
[Run-time String Collection Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3c6G.png)

I can edit or remove the entries just fine, but if I try to add one, I get the following error:
"Constructor in type 'System.string' not found".

Is there a simple way to have property grid use the same editor the design-time editing of the Settings does?

Comment: You have to use custom object with properties and assign editor via attribute. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46099675/1997232). I don't know which editor is this modal window with multiline string.